# Cocoa - Method to count the characters in a text field?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm pretty new to objective C started a few days ago...

I want to count all the chars in a text field. Could

[textField length]

be useful at all and how do I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSUInteger len = [[textField stringValue] length];
```